# Reversed linked list - Issue with logic

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I'm working on the following problem [Reverse Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/) from Leetcode:

> Given the head of a singly linked list, reverse the list, and return the reversed list.
>
> Class `ListNode` defined as follows:
>
> ```
>  public class ListNode {
>     int val;
>     ListNode next;
>     ListNode() {}
>     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
>     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
> }
> ```

Here is the solution that I came up with.

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
        if (head != null) {
            ListNode pre = head;
            ListNode cur = head.next;
            ListNode temp;
            while (cur != null) {
                temp = cur.next;
                cur.next = pre; 
                pre = pre.next; //here should be pre = cur; but I don't get it.
                cur = temp;
            }
            head.next = null;
            return pre;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

To make it working inside the `while`-loop, I need change

```
pre = pre.next;
```

with

```
pre = cur;
```

But I still don't fully understand it.

After `temp = cur.next;`, variable `pre` should still be pointing to `cur`, right?

So what's wrong here? Can someone explain it in detail?

Comment: It is just : `pre.next == cur` at this point (as invariant!(?)), but `pre = cur;`  is better readable/fail safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `pre` should still be pointing to `cur`, right? So what's wrong here?
>
> ```
> pre = pre.next; // here should be pre = cur; but I don't get it.
> ```

When the `while`-loop terminates, `cur` points to `null`, so you need a reference to the previous node `pre` as a result.

Now let's take a closer look at the statement

```
pre = pre.next;
```

During the first step of iteration when `pre` points to `head`, this statement would be the same as `pre = cur` (effectively `head.next`). That fine.

But starting from the second iteration step, `pre.next` would point **backwards**, and that not what you need. You need to advance the reference `pre` to the *tail* (which would became a *new head*), not the opposite.

For that reason, you need `pre = cur;` instead.

You can get rid of the `if`-statement in your code and reimplement it like this:

```
public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
    ListNode pre = null;
    ListNode cur = head;
    while (cur != null) {
        ListNode temp = cur.next;
        cur.next = pre;
        pre = cur;
        cur = temp;
    }
    return pre;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListNode second = new ListNode(3);
    ListNode first = new ListNode(2, second);
    ListNode head = new ListNode(1, first);

    ListNode newHead = reverseList(head);
    while (newHead != null) {
        System.out.println(newHead.val);
        newHead = newHead.next;
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
3
2
1
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/ubr)

Comment: Hi thank you so much! I figured it out just minutes after posing this question. Huge thank you for giving a such detailed explanation and putting effort into revising my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reverse singly linked list than I can give you a simpler solution

```
public class ListReverser {
    public static Node<Integer> reverse(Node head) {
        Node current = head;
        while(current.getNext() != null) {
            Node next =  current.getNext();
            current.setNext(next.getNext());
            next.setNext(head);
            head = next;
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

I wrote a small post on my LinkedIn page with this solution. Feel free to visit: [Popular Java interview task: Reverse singly (one-directional) linked list](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/popular-java-interview-task-reverse-singly-linked-list-gantman/)